# How to use Spring Boot PrePersist with lombok NonNull

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Spring and am having a lot of trouble getting Entities configured correctly while using null safety.

My goal is to avoid duplicating models. For example, I would prefer to now have a Customer entity, along with a CreateCustomer model.

What I am trying to do is something like

```
@Entity
public class Customer {


    @Column
    @NonNull private Date timestamp;

    @PrePersist
    private void prePersistFunction(){
        if (this.timestamp == null) {
            this.timestamp = new Date();
        }
    }




}
```

The issue is what happens if I want to create a customer object? I don't want to pass that a timestamp but I want timestamp to be marked with @NonNull for when I do getCustomer()

Any recommendations would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you don’t pass a timestamp during creation, where do you expect to get it from when retrieving the object? Are you expecting the database to set a default value?

Answer (score 0):

So the @PrePersist method is called *only* when you're putting a new customer in the database.

You can make the empty constructor not be public and have a different constructor that requires a timestamp. Or perhaps have a static creation method:

```java
public static Customer newCustomer() {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.timestamp = new Date();
    return customer;
}
```